# Is it a bad practice to override setState and add a mounted check inside

Tags: flutter

It is necessary to check `mounted` before setting the state when it is called after a long (async) operation.

```
if (!mounted) {
  return;
}
```

I found that another option that works is to override `setState` and move the check to there, my page has multiple `setState` areas so this can reduce code by removing complexity

```
  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    super.setState(fn);
  }
```

I suspect that overriding `setState` is a bad practice and wanted to open it here.

Is it bad practice to override "setState"?

Comment: I would suspect you want to terminate the entire async function that called this, though.  That's why burying this return seems like a bad idea.  You need to return from the caller of setState, not just nullify the setState itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hence, it's a good practice to use mounted whenever you use setState as well as when you are performing some operations which includes the use of context because even the context can get changed or updated.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html